# How to pass data of Recyclerview.Viewholder into another Activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

Is it possible to pass data from a Recyclerview's Viewholder into another activity. for example I want to pass the Checkbox itembox which i declared inside Viewholder now i want to pass it into another activity lets say Validity.class so i can perform a performClick method inside that activity. is it possible to do?

Comment: you need to read first **[ask]**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LocalBroadcastManager`. [How to use LocalBroadcastManager?](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html)